# eval() and PHP errors

Tags: php, error-handling, eval

I have a eval function like this

```
if(FALSE === @eval($code)) echo 'your code has php errors';
```

So if the code has synthax errors it will return that message.

The problem is that if within the code you have something like:

```
  require_once('missing_file.php');
```

it will just break the page, without my nice error message :(

Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Also, please don't put `false` on the left hand side of the `===`. It makes me queasy...

Comment: but i have very justified reason to use eval().
I want the site admin to have the ability to add his own php code, instead of editing the application files (and loosing his changes when he updates the app).

Comment: @Alex Some kind of pluggable architecture would be infinitely better than having them store PHP code in a string somewhere and evaling it

Comment: this is based on wordpress, which is already pluggable. but some users might want a simple web interface for this, like a textarea with codemirror on it.

Comment: @Alex - and what happens when your user gives away a password or leaves it somewhere? Or they use 'password' and someone guesses it? Your server will be rooted. Don't eval unchecked code from the web. It's a very very bad idea.

Comment: well it's the user's problem, it's his website :)
Wordpress already offers the admins the ability to edit plugin/theme php files directly from the administration area. This is exactly the same thing, but the code is saved into the database and runs with eval() on initialization. The problem I have is with these fatal errors, which break the entire site and prevent the user to access the admin area to fix his code :(

Comment: WordPress is generally, not written very well. Look at their long string of major security flaws. They really use `eval` on that editable code in the admin areas? Horrifying. A better alternative might be to save the entry as a file, and then use `include` or `require`, which will evaluate all the code. It's not more secure, but it would work a lot better.  An even better alternative would be to find a way to use a real templating system like Smarty or H20, and then the server couldn't be broken as easily and would be a lot more secure. I can't believe WordPress still doesn't do that.

Comment: no, they don't use eval on that, they just allow you to edit php files stored on the server.
I do, because I want the site admin not to edit those files. Editing files will make him loose the changes he made if he updates the app. That's the entire point of the eval() thing...

Comment: I understand all the security risks of eval(), but in this case the only security problem i can see is if a 3rd party application accesses the database field where my app's code is stored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, first I hope that `$code` comes from a trusted source and that you're executing arbitrary code sent by the users.

Second, the only way I see you can workaround that is to save `$code` into a file, run it with the command line PHP interpreter, and check the exit value. Note that passing this test doesn't make `$code` fatal error free, it just so happened that this particular execution of the script did not throw any fatal error; there may be other code paths that trigger such an error.

This is because once `eval` triggers a fatal error, it can't be recovered and the script dies. `eval` only returns `FALSE` if there is a parsing error.

Comment: only file including functions like 'require' cause fatal errors?

Comment: @Alex No, there are many conditions that trigger fatal error.

Comment: Not knowing PHP too well - could you try/catch the `eval`, or does that not work?